# Objects being constructed correctly?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, initialization

I was wondering if this abstract data type that I'm making is being constructed correctly.

**My constructors:**

```
   IntSet();                                 
   IntSet(int a, int = -1, int = -1, int = -1, int = -1);
```

**IntSets being created in main:**

```
IntSet A();
IntSet B;
```

Right now A is constructed in the 5 value constructor and B is constructed in the empty constructor. Would this be correct, or should A be constructed in the empty constructor as well?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe a word of what you're saying. `A` is a function, not an object. It doesn't look like you've made *any* effort to verify your hypothesis (e.g. print a message in each constructor, or access the members afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IntSet A();
```

This line **declares a function** which takes no parameter and return `IntSet` type. It does not define an object. It's also known as [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

```
IntSet B;
```

This line defines object `B` by calling default constructor(the constructor which takes 0 parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Right now, B is default constructed.

A isn't a definition of an object at all though. It's a declaration of a function named `A` that takes no arguments and returns an `IntSet`. Googling for "most vexing parse" will provide lots more explanations and discussions.